# Add additional record with same reference ID

Tags: forms, ms-access-2013

I'm working in Access 2013. I'm building forms to guide/constrain data entry for field personnel. Vistable holds Visit records: one record per visit with date, start/stop times, other visit specific information. Obstable holds observations made on each visit, and the table are related in a 1 Vistable : Many Obstable relationship.

I've built a form to enter new visits, and there is a button for entering related observations. Clicking the button saves the visit record, sets a tempvar (tempVisID) and when the Obsform is openned, the VisID field is set = tempVisID so that the parent and child records are linked in the underlying tables.

After entering an observation, one can exit the obsform back to the Visform or add another observation, distinct from the last. In that case, the Obstable.ID field should increment but I need the Obstable.VisID field to remain = tempVisID because both observations should link back to the same visit record. However, everything I've tried so far throws an error or automatically increments the VisID. I.e. if I just go to a new obs record, it increments, though I don't think it should (the field in the underlying table is a text field, not indexed, not autonumber), and if I try to use a default value = the tempVisID or anything else (so far) it throws an error saying "The value you entered isn't valid for this field" and then I'm forced to abort the entry screen. This most recent attempt I used a macro to GoToRecord=New, and SetProperty of the VisID value=tempVisID.

Any suggestions for how to get the VisID to remain the same? I'm at a loss and I'm sure it is something simple I'm missing. Important note. I DO NOT know or understand VBA and don't have time to try and add that to my toolbox at the moment. I'm stuck working with macros and expressions.

Comment: This is extremely hard to follow the way it is written. I'd suggest adding screenshots of your table design, relationships, forms or anything else that might help us visualize your situation

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I finally settled on. When you finish entering Visit data, you click the 'Add Obs' button. This action does three things: 1. Sets a TempVar = Visit.ID (primary key of Visit table), 2. SaveRecord stores the visit record in the Visit table (otherwise I got an error saying my child record in Observations didn't have a connected parent in Visit), and 3. Opens the AddObservations form. The AddObservation.VisID field is then set, using a default value control, to be the TempVar set above. The user then enters the rest of the data and exits the form back to Visits, or clicks the "AddAnotherObs" button. My workaround was thus:
AddAnotherObs simply closes the Observation form, then immediately reopens it. Since the TempVar hasn't changed, the default value resets to the same value, allowing me to add a second observation on the same visit. Anything else I tried incremented the Visit.ID field and then generated an error because there was no parent record with that ID (and if there was it would be the wrong parent!).

Sorry if my original post wasn't as well explained as you might have liked. I tried to make it as clear as possible. I don't think I'm up to a level where I can post screenshots and such.